# Converting row into columns and getting sum and max

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with contains the rows like below. Here the staDt and remarksvalue are not static.

[image]

I have written a query that converts the rows to columns but I could not get the sum of asm1,asm2 and asm3 for each row. Then I also want the date and max value when the max of sum of (asm1,asm2 and asm3) occurs with the same query.
Right now, I have the query like below to transpose the rows to columns as below.

```
SELECT  [asm1], [asm2],[asm3],stadt FROM (SELECT row_number() over(partition by remarksvalue order by  stadt desc ) as [RowNumber], 
 remarks, remarksvalue,stadt FROM dbo.SBSTest1  WITH(NOLOCK) where staDt>='04/17/2014' and 
 staDt<='04/22/2014' )
 as t PIVOT (MIN(remarksvalue) FOR remarks IN ([asm1], [asm2],[asm3])) as p order by stadt desc.
```

Now, how can I get the sum of each row, date & max value when the max of sum of (asm1,asm2 and asm3) occurs with the same query? Any other method is appreciated as well.

### create script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SBSTest1]([staDt] [datetime] NULL,[remarksValue] [int] NULL,[remarks] nvarchar](10) NULL,[id] [int] NULL)
```

### insert script

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SBSTest1]([staDt],[remarksValue],[remarks],id)VALUES('2014-04-18 13:07:00.000',1,'asm1',1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SBSTest1]([staDt],[remarksValue],[remarks],id)VALUES('2014-04-18 13:07:00.000',21,'asm2',2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SBSTest1]([staDt],[remarksValue],[remarks],id)VALUES('2014-04-18 13:07:00.000',141,'asm3',3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SBSTest1]([staDt],[remarksValue],[remarks],id)VALUES('2014-04-19 13:07:00.000',29,'asm1',4)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SBSTest1]([staDt],[remarksValue],[remarks],id)VALUES('2014-04-19 11:07:00.000',33,'asm2',5)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SBSTest1]([staDt],[remarksValue],[remarks],id)VALUES('2014-04-20 10:08:00.000',99,'asm3',6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SELECT  [asm1], [asm2],[asm3],stadt 
FROM (
SELECT  remarks, remarksvalue, CAST(stadt AS DATE) AS stadt 
 FROM dbo.SBSTest1  
 where staDt>='04/17/2014' and staDt<='04/22/2014')as t 
 PIVOT (SUM(remarksvalue) 
        FOR remarks 
        IN ([asm1], [asm2],[asm3])) as p 
order by stadt desc
```

**Result**

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦════════════╗
║ asm1 ║ asm2 ║ asm3 ║   stadt    ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬════════════╣
║ NULL ║ NULL ║ 99   ║ 2014-04-20 ║
║ 29   ║ 33   ║ NULL ║ 2014-04-19 ║
║ 1    ║ 21   ║ 141  ║ 2014-04-18 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩════════════╝
```

*Note*

There are no values in your provided data set which will actually sum up by pivoting in this format, if you had more values for `[asm1], [asm2] or [asm3]` under one date they would sum up when you pivot your rows.

If you want to see a simple SUM of all the  `[asm1], [asm2] or [asm3]` values in columns just exclude the date column from your pivot query. something like this....

```
SELECT  [asm1], [asm2],[asm3]
FROM (
SELECT  remarks, remarksvalue 
 FROM dbo.SBSTest1  
 where staDt>='04/17/2014' and staDt<='04/22/2014')as t 
 PIVOT (SUM(remarksvalue) 
        FOR remarks 
        IN ([asm1], [asm2],[asm3])) as p
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ asm1 ║ asm2 ║ asm3 ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║   30 ║   54 ║  240 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

**Update**

After reading your comments I feel like I have done all this work for nothing :) well since you have mentioned now that you would like to sum values as `asm + asm2 + asm3` that is fairly simple. see below:

```
SELECT  ISNULL([asm1], 0) + ISNULL([asm2], 0) + ISNULL([asm3], 0) AS [Total]
       ,stadt 
FROM (
SELECT  remarks, remarksvalue, CAST(stadt AS DATE) AS stadt 
 FROM dbo.SBSTest1  
 where staDt>='04/17/2014' and staDt<='04/22/2014')as t 
 PIVOT (SUM(remarksvalue) 
        FOR remarks 
        IN ([asm1], [asm2],[asm3])) as p 
order by stadt desc
```

Comment: I want sum of asm + asm2 + asm3 of pivoted tables not SUM of all the  [asm1], [asm2] or [asm3]. So there is no way I can do that ?

Comment: Opss I have done all this work for nothing than.... see my update and please accept the answer if it helped you thank you.

Comment: Ok thanks but what about the max sum and date when that occurs with the same query ? Is that possible ? ( I don't want to use top 1 * order by total desc because I want it to be sorted by stadt)

Comment: You should ask a separate question :) there is nothing wrong with asking for explanation but you are extending your question now, anyway you can use TOP 1 which will be the easiest option for you or you can use row number functions to get the maximum value but I think it will make things a little but complicated unnecessarily.

Comment: I have asked about max sum and date at the top.